# Xamarin, auto Detect installation Type

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I develop an app for a client.
This client want to install my app with the APK for users and for some other users, this app could be downloaded for AppleStore/PlayStore.

Currently I developed two version , one for an APK version and another one for stores.
For one feature is not the same comportment for store version or apk version.

It's not possible to have just store version.

Is it possible for my app, to auto detect her installation type? 
With this I could  configure my app without checking any value in bdd and consume data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally , 
i used Xamarin.Essentials, with this package i am able to detect previous version on my device. 
i tested it on android.
i used this to detect previous version:

```
 VersionTracking.FirstInstalledVersion
 VersionTracking.VersionHistory.ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your easiest method would be to add a new Build Configuration and add a Compilation symbol that you utilize in your code.

Comment: Yes , i agree with you, i did this yesterday but i don't like it because it doesn't automatic.   currently it works.